# Accessing widgets inside a master widget for sequential gridding

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I am using `ttk` (themed tkinter) to create GUI. Here my goal is to `grid` the widgets inside a `master` widget in **columns of three**. Here is a snippet of the widgets inside `keypad` master widget.

```
[...]
nine = ttk.Button(keypad, text='9')
eight = ttk.Button(keypad, text='8')
seven = ttk.Button(keypad, text='7')
six = ttk.Button(keypad, text='6')
five = ttk.Button(keypad, text='5')
four = ttk.Button(keypad, text='4')
three = ttk.Button(keypad, text='3')
two = ttk.Button(keypad, text='2')
one = ttk.Button(keypad, text='1')
[...]
```

The long way would be to indvidually grid every slave widget, which makes the code writing *repetitiv*e and *cumbersome*.

```
[...]
nine = ttk.Button(keypad, text='9').grid(row=2, column=0)
eight = ttk.Button(keypad, text='8').grid(row=2, column=1)
seven = ttk.Button(keypad, text='7').grid(row=2, column=2
[...]
```

Is there a way to access each slave widget and grid it in **columns of three** like itterating over a list?

P.S. The desired end result should look like this(I did using the *cumbersome* method, here there are 4 columns!):

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use `for` loop to create them?

Comment: How do I access the widgets of ```master``` using ```for``` loop?

Comment: Don't know what do you want to do.`for i in your_list:i.master`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do an array of buttons. First, prepare a 5x4 array of labels:

```
labels = [['*', '/', 'C', 'AC'],
          ['9', '8', '7', '-'],
          ['4', '5', '6', '+'],
          ['3', '2', '1', '='],
          ['.', '0', '+/-', 'Copy']]
```

Then creates the buttons using for loops:

```
buttons = []

for i in range(len(labels)):
    buttons.append([])
    for j in range(len(labels[i])):
        b = ttk.Button(keypad, text=labels[i][j])
        buttons[i].append(b)
        b.grid(row=i, column=j)
```

Now, `buttons` is a 5x4 array of `ttk.Button`, and you can access the one you want with `buttons[row][column]`.